# Spreading the word about the GameDev chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

The [GameDev chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73/game-development) could be a great extension to the site, but only if people are going to utilize it. Earlier today a few of us were talking about ways to spread the word, and possibly have a big push for a chat meetup later in the week.

How do you feel about the idea? Would you be interested in such an event? How could we spread the word to get people interested?

Comment: This has been handled. The Chatroom is available on the right sidebar now.

Answer (score 3):

Without an agenda a meeting is a waste of time.  Unless your goal is just to shoot the shit.

The best thing we can do is what I did earlier today and make it a system message at the top of the page.  That, and if you like the idea of a chat room either idle in there or keep coming back.  Beyond that any additional pushing is probably not sustainable.

Comment: Organised meetups are also going to have real time-zone issues...

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to have a button labelled 'Chat Room' or similar along the main navigation bar? That would certainly spread the word.

As for a meetup, I'm sure there could be a time that is accessible to most users.

Comment: Not just yet. The Chatrooms are currently in public beta, and they aren't even completely deployed. Our room is *technically* in violation because chats on MSO are supposed to have topics relating to MSO.

Comment: But still, post it as a feature request. I'd upvote and see if the Devs will pay attention :)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason people don't visit a chatroom is because they are often somewhat empty. So how about adding a tracker that displays total number of people chatting, biggest chatroom and number of people in that chatroom?

Comment: This discussion is 3+ years old at this point. The chatroom box on the sidebar displays a list of the users who are currently logged in, and the extra information is available on the general chat frontpage.